# How to reject a promise on NativeScript - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a code that works in angular 2, but when I try to use it in a nativescript project fails. 
I´m trying to reject a promise like this:

```
login(credentials:Credentials):Promise<User> {
    if (!valid) {
         return Promise.reject<User>("Invalid password");
    }else {
         return Promise.resolve(new User("some user"));
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Error:(32, 22) TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>You missed to return promise when you Rejected it.
Error directly says that you aren't returning `Promise<User>` from function. As method return type is `Promise<User>`, it always return that object.</strike>

**PS:** After edit in OP found that method can return two types of data, on success it would be `User` object, on reject its `string`. So for such case I'd prefer you to change the method return type to `User | string`

**Code**

```
login(credentials:Credentials):Promise<User | string> {
    if (!valid) {
         //returned promise here which was missing and failing compilation
         return Promise.reject("Invalid password");
    }else {
         return Promise.resolve(new User("some user"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thats is not the problem! I´m forget to put it on the question, but I have it on the code! I will edit the question.

Comment: Thanks! But `Promise.reject<User>("Invalid password");` doesn't return a Promise<User> ??

Comment: @DiegoGonzález no, `Promise.reject<User>("Something")` isn't correct syntax, as you can't say `<User>` in between while you are calling reject function. Also whatever is inside parenthesis `reject("Something")` that get returned. In reject function case its `string` where, where as return `User` object correctly from `resolve` function

Comment: In typescript? I been using that syntax in other projects with no problem. I think that its a problem with the typescript compiler options.

Comment: @DiegoGonzález no, it isn't. Because here you were trying to apply that on `reject` method, which obiviously isn't valid

Comment: Even using es6?

Comment: Yes, can you give a sample code where you used it? I'll try to explain you that.

Comment: @DiegoGonzález does my updated solution worked for you?

Comment: The problem is that I used that in a entire project but in one project compile and in other doesn't. Navigating to source in the ide I found the function declaration:    
  /**
     * Creates a new rejected promise for the provided reason.
     * param reason The reason the promise was rejected.
     * returns A new rejected Promise.
     */
    reject<T>(reason: any): Promise<T>;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125544/discussion-between-diego-gonzalez-and-pankaj-parkar).